# Necesito imprimir solo las dos primeras vocales de una palabra en c

Tags: c

Necesito imprimir solo las dos primeras vocales de una palabra en c.
Ejemplo:                Computadora
imprimir solo:              ou.

Lo intente de muchas formas pero ninguna me funciona.

Comment: podrías aclarar un poco tu pregunta? y por favor colocar algo de código para depurar? Así te ayudamos más rapidamente. Un Saludo!

Comment: ¿Para la palabra alambre tiene que imprimir `aa`, o `ae`?

Comment: Deberías mostrar las muchas formas que has intentado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Hola!

Mi solución sería algo más o menos así.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char cadena[20];

    printf("Ingrese una cadena: "); //Ingreso la cadena por teclado.
    scanf("%s", cadena); //Leo la cadena.

    tolower(cadena); //Hago todas las letras de la cadena minusculas.

    printf("\n\nLas 2 primeras vocales son: ");

    /*inicializo la variable i para el ciclo for y recorrer toda la cadena, y tambien una variable cont para contar cuantas vocales he encontrado.*/
    int i = 0, cont = 0;  

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(cadena); i++){

        /*A medida que recorro el vector, si en alguna posición i que recorre el vector, la letra es una vocal, la imprimo y aumento
        el contador en 2, por eso la condicion de que cont < 2, por que si no seguiría imprimiendo todas las vocales de la cadena.*/

        if( (cadena[i] == 'a' || cadena[i] == 'e' || cadena[i] == 'i' || cadena[i] == 'o' || cadena[i] == 'u') && cont < 2 ){
            cont ++;
            printf(" %c ", cadena[i]); //imprimo las vocales.
        }
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

¡Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: A modo de pequeña mejora... yo no seguiría iterando después de alcanzar `cont==2`. Quizás `for(i = 0; i < strlen(cadena) && cont < 2; i++){` o poner un `break`

Comment: Por otro lado no tiene demasiado sentido que te quejes de que no ha intentado nada y a la vez le respondas :S